Postgresql TIME to proto timestamppb conversion giving negative value
I have a field in the postgres with TIME datatype. For GRPC in proto file as time.Time is not supported, so I'm using google.protobuf.Timestamp.
message Msg {
  string id = 1;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp registered_time = 2;
}

The query is executed using squirrel package in golang. Please correct me if any mistake in the conversion I'm doing.
var (
    string id
    resgisteredTime time.Time
)
s.builder.Select("id", "regsitered_time").
    From("user_table").
    Where(sq.Eq{"id": r.Id}).
    QueryRowContext(ctx).
    Scan(
        &id,
        &registedTime,
    ); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return &storage.Result {
    ID: id,
    RegisteredTime: timestamppb.New(registeredTime),
}, nil

The response I get is
{
    "id": "362b57d8-1ca6-498a-8714-cab81e1d9dd6",
    "registered_time": {
        "seconds": "-62167190400",
        "nanos": 0
    }
}

On debugging I can see that timestamppd supports date from 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31. But in my case, for value for DB the date is taken as 0000-01-01. Because of this it is negative. How to get the proper value and in proper readable format.

There isn't a year 0000. Before 0001-01-01 is 0001-12-31 BC. Where are you getting 0000 from?

I think the issue is that Postgres is returning Epoch in milliseconds and Go is assuming the value is seconds. Using Epoch Converter with -62167190400 converts the milliseconds to 12-Jan-1968 11:20:09.600. Is that the value you're expecting? In your example the JSON shows "seconds": "-62167190400" but I think this represents milliseconds?

Assuming (!?) you're use of &registedTime is a typo
